# Magento 2.x.x extension attributes API add object array

Tags: api, extension-attributes, magento2.3.5, custom-extension

Have added custom attribute to order API with following info here: https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/adding-custom-attribute-to-api-response-in-magento-2/

It adds the `"customer_feedback": "this is my feedback"` fine to api.

How to add an Json object array ? E.G:

```
"my_custom_object": {
    "Key1": "value!",
    "Key2": "value2"
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I sourced out the answer to my question!.

**One simple cannot do:**

```
$my_custom_object = array("Key1" => "value!") 
OR
$my_custom_object = json_encode(array("Key1" => "value!"));
```

It expect the value to be an object:
So setting customAttribute like so:

```
$extensionAttributes->setOurCustomData($ourCustomData);
```

`$ourCustomData`  Must be an object:
So I create Interface with getter and setter and a model that implements the interface and in `extension_attributes.xml`:

```
...
<attribute code="our_custom_data" type="Vendor\Module\Api\Data\CustomInterface"/>
...
```

In Plugin orderRepository:

Inject model : `\Vendor\Module\Model\CustomModel $customModel`

```
...
$ourCustomData = $this->customModel;
$extensionAttributes->setOurCustomData($ourCustomData);
...
```

Hope it helps anyone!